# Templates - Can this be done?

Tags: c++, types

Quick question (Theory really). I have a variable that its type alternates depending on a value, for example:

```
8, 16, 24, 32
```

And I define this by doing, for example:

```
uint8_t = 10; // example
```

But, at the minute I'm switching the "number" and repeating the code but declaring the integer value differently. Which, as you can tell, is a lot of wasteful code and I want to code more effectively.

I'm wondering if It's possible to have template that assigns the variable depending on the value? (If that makes sense)..

```
if value == 8
  uint8_t = foo;
elseif value == 16
  uint32_t
...
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: What variable? And where's the template? Also... wat?

Comment: Going by the values you show, you want different types depending on some sort of bit-counter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like so:

```
template <unsigned int N> struct IntN;

template <> struct IntN< 8> { typedef  uint8_t type; };
template <> struct IntN<16> { typedef uint16_t type; };
template <> struct IntN<32> { typedef uint32_t type; };
template <> struct IntN<64> { typedef uint64_t type; };

IntN<8>::type x = 5;
```

The template argument has to be a constant expression.

Comment: Ahh, you are faster.  You need `typename` on last line.

Comment: @Leonid: Only if the `8` was a non-type template parameter.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: I call that into question.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky No, you don't, since you're instantiating the template directly. You would only need it if the template argument (the `8`) was itself a template parameter from a surrounding template.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I think the phrase you're looking for is "if `type` is a dependent name" :-)

Comment: I see. Didn't know that.  I won't delete my 1st comment so that ppl will know what we are talking about.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know this phrase, just wasn't sure if the addressand of my comment was aware of its meaning, too. Though I also see that my explanation is a bit awkward.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the reply, by this method, I would still need an if statement, right?

Comment: @Phorce: No. Static programming like that is done via templates and specialization.

Comment: In which way switching from `Int<8> x = 5` to `Int<16> x = 10` is better than switching from `int_8 x = 5` to `int_16 x = 10`

Comment: @PiotrNycz: because you can say `run_algorithm<sizeof x>(arg1, arg2, arg3)` generically :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I dont understand your example, since sizeof int8 == sizeof Int<8>::type, but I understand the question. I thought OP wanted sth like Int<10>::type x = 10; for every number, not only 8,16,.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Sorry, `x` was just a randomly made-up name, not connected to the answer. With more work you can also provide specializations for the entire range (using `std::conditional`).

Comment: @KerrekSB I just misunderstood the question. I know how to make specialization for entire range, I just thought OP wanted such answer.